# Can not change object property value

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript, I have tried this:

```
object1 = {};
object2 = Object.create(object1, {a:{value:1}});
object2.a = 2;
```

Then if I display object2.a, it is still 1 instead of 2. why is that?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this post about object creation patterns and you will have a much better understanding of the difference between object1 and object2 in your example. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/687093/Understanding-JavaScript-Object-Creation-Patterns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because `Object.create()` is not what you think.

see this [ECMAScript 5: Object creation and property definition](http://www.jimmycuadra.com/posts/ecmascript-5-object-creation-and-property-definition/)

> There are three additional aspects of a property we can control, each given a boolean value:
>
> 1. `writable`: Controls whether or not the property can be assigned. If `false`, attempts at assignment will fail. Only applies to data descriptors.
> 2. `enumerable`: Controls whether or not this property will appear in `for...in` loops.
> 3. `configurable`: Controls whether or not the property can be deleted, and whether its property descriptor (other than `writable`) can be changed.
>
> Each of these defaults to `false` if not supplied.

so what you need is :

```
var object1 = {};
var object2 = Object.create(object1, {
    a: {
        value: 1,
        writable: true
    },
});
object2.a = 2;
```

Have fun : )

Comment: Thanks.  There is a sentence in the article "writable: Controls whether or not the property can be assigned. If true, attempts at assignment will fail. Only applies to data descriptors."

I am confused by it, it said, if true, assignment will fail. but default is false, means assignment will be ok?. is there something wrong with
that sentence?  should "if true" be "if false"?

Comment: @totally: Indeed, that logic is messed up

Comment: @totally that's a mistake , sorry for that ; p

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var object1 = {};
var object2 = Object.create(object1, {a:{value:1,writable: true}});
object2.a = 2;
```

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties